# Raspberry Pi 3+ and MATLAB

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi3

I am attempting to connect MATLAB with a Raspberry Pi 3+.  Using the application installer in MATLAB, I downloaded and installed the necessary support hardware (https://www.mathworks.com/hardware-support/raspberry-pi-matlab.html) and then used the configuration dialog in those apps to flash a microSD card.  Booting the Pi with that card, I set up passwordless sudo and enabled SSH.  Using an ethernet cable to connect my laptop with the Pi, I can ping the Pi from MATLAB, and I can SSH in using PuTTy.  However, when I try to connect in MATLAB (having opened MATLAB in admin mode), I get the following error:

[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here -- this error isn't listed on MATLAB's help page, and I cannot find anything online.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the pi@ from the device address

Comment: That was it -- thank you!  That's what I get for trying to blindly follow directions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is straightfoward: problem found between user and keyboard.  The device address should ONLY be the IP address of the Pi.